# Given $|u-y|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, $u,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, proving $|u^n-y^n|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ by induction.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

Here is the full version of the question:
Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\epsilon>0$, show that for some $\delta > 0$, if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|u−y| < \delta$ then $|u^n −y^n| < \epsilon$. [Hint: Prove the inequality when n = 1, n = 2, and then do induction on n using the identity
$$u^n-y^n=(u-y)(u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1})$$

I am trying to solve this question from Pugh. While the question recommends using induction, I don't take advantage of the induction hypothesis. Here is my attempt:

Given $|u-y|<\delta$, the base case is trivial such that $\delta=\epsilon$. Then given any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{|u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|}$. By the given hint, using my definition of $\epsilon$:
$$\implies |u^n-y^n|\leq |u-y||u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|<\delta |u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|=\epsilon$$

As you can see, I don't use $|u^{n-1}-y^{n-1}|<\epsilon$. Is this solution valid? Do I have the freedom the define the $\delta$ in the question as I wish?

Comment: You are given $y, n,$ and $\epsilon$, and must choose a $\delta$ that works for any $u$.

Comment: Hmm. I am thinking of using $|u-y|<\delta$ to assert that $|u|<|y|+\delta$, which I can then use to bound the expression: $|u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|\leq |(|y|+\delta)^{n-1}|+|(|y|+\delta)^{n-2}y|+\cdots+|y^{n-1}|$. Then using the same inequality as above, I find that: $$|u^n-y^n|<\delta(|(|y|+\delta)^{n-1}|+|(|y|+\delta)^{n-2}y|+\cdots+|y^{n-1}|)=\epsilon$$ Can I choose $\delta$ satisfying this equality or is it too vague?

Comment: You must ***choose*** $\delta$ before you are given $u$. You can think of it as a two player game in which I give you $y$, $n$, and $\epsilon$, then you choose $\delta$, and if I can find a $u$ that violates the condition, you lose.  You cannot use $u$ to pick your $\delta$ because I'm not going to tell you $u$ until after you pick your $\delta$.

Comment: I appreciate your guidance. However, I am confused as to how I might be able to choose $\delta$ without the presence of a $u$. For example, I am trying to build up from the $n=2$ case. I have that $|u^2-y^2|<\epsilon$. Multiplying both sides by $|\frac{1}{u+y}|$ gives me: $|u-y|\leq\frac{|u^2-y^2|}{|u+y|}<\frac{\epsilon}{|u+y|}$. In essence, I am looking for what values would work in place of $|u-y|<\delta$. However, I don't know how to get rid of the $u$ dependence here. Could I have a further hint if possible as to how I can choose $\delta$ without using $u$?

Comment: Yes, there's a standard technique which perhaps you haven't seen yet. You don't get to know $u$, but ***you*** get to choose $\delta$, so you need to choose a $\delta$ that forces $u$ to be as close as you need to $y$, then all of your statements about $u$ need to follow from $|u-y|<\delta$

Comment: For example, if $0<\delta<|y|$, then $|u-y|<\delta \implies |u|<2|y|$, so $$|u-y||u+y|<\delta (3|y|)$$

Comment: I thought we couldn't assume $\delta<|y|$, because the question says for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and there exists reals $|r|<\delta$. However, I see how that assumption is very useful, as for the case of $n$: we have $|u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}y+\cdots+y^{n-1}|<\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i |y^{n-1}|$, which allows us to find $|u^n-y^n|<\delta (\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i |y^{n-1}|)$. I would be glad if you could clarify why we can go with $\delta<|y|$ when we are asked for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Or is this another case I should consider?

Comment: Well, you are correct that if $y=0$ then we cannot take $\delta<|y|$, since we are required to choose $\delta>0$. But if $y\ne 0$, then we can choose $\delta$ so that $0<\delta<|y|$. We don't need to worry about the fact that there are real numbers less than $\delta$, because $y$ has already been specified ***before*** you choose $\delta$. The order of the quantifiers is very important in problems.

Comment: Usually, in these problems, we would specify an exact formula for $\delta$, and often it involves taking the minimum of multiple quantities, such as $\delta =\min(\epsilon/2, |y|/2)$, or, to make sure it's positive: $\delta =\min(\epsilon/2, \max(|y|/2,1))$